# Band in a Box 64 bit 2021 & Window Media Player 64 bit

Tags: wine, 64-bit

I'm looking for a way to install Windows Media Player on a 64 bit Wine as Band in a Box 2021 64bit uses it to preview demo wma in it's dialogs.
"System Requirements for Band-in-a-Box · Windows®: Vista / 7 / 8 / 8.1 / 10 (32 or 64-bit) · "
It needs to be in the same 64 bit wine for Band in a Box to use.

I have been trying it on different Linux Distros with wine wine-staging wine-development Crossover... Ubutu seems to be the closest to working on using Crossover.

Can I copy some files from from Win10/7 to get it to work ?

I'm getting OLE error 80004002 opening these dialogs that have the play buttons. I put VLC on it but Biab can't use it. WMP plays the wma demos.

This is native on Windows
[image: This is native on Windows 10]

This is Wine on Linux
[image: This is Wine on Linux]

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *The only OS you specifically mention is off-topic windows, Linux refers to a kernel and is unspecific & covered in SE Unix & Linux unless Ubuntu or flavor of Ubuntu but you were unspecific*

Comment: You'd have better luck at `winehq.org`.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=35420&p=133539#p133539